# JSON value from NSDictionary content an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

This is my code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"action", @"type", @"entry", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"action1", @"one", entry.identifier, nil];
```

the entry must be an array so it one example of output must be:

```
"entry": [ "entry" ]
```

inside the `"[ ]"` how can I do that?
With my code I get `"entry":  "entry"`

Comment: You're missing the outer `{}`, denoting an "object" (NSDictionary).  (Hint:  Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store an array instead of a single value, you…well, you store an array instead of a single value.

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"action1", @"one", [NSArray arrayWithObject:entry.identifier], nil];
```